# How can I detect clicks on an AnimatedSprite2D in Godot with C#?

Tags: c#, godot, godot4

I'm Learing Godot and I want the program detect when I press the left mouse button, but when I press only on the animation sprite I can't detect when click on an AnimatedSprite2D

```
public override void _Input(InputEvent @event)
{
    if (@event is InputEventMouseButton mouseEvent)
    {
        if(@event is InputEventMouseButton e && !e.Pressed && e.ButtonIndex == MouseButton.Left)
        {
            Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

If I do it like this the animation stops regardless of where I click.

If someone can help me I would be so thankful

Answer (score 0):

If this was a Control the solution would be to use `_GuiInput` instead of `_Input`, but `AnimatedSprite2D` is not a `Control`.

The `Node2D` such as `AnimatedSprite2D` do not have an inherent concept of size (the visual size of some of them is given by their current `Texture`, but this is not used in the input pipeline at all).

Thus, the easier way to do this is to add an `Area2D` to which you can add `CollisionShape2D` or `CollisionPolygon2D` to define the clickable area, and then handle the input in `_input_event` (`_InputEvent` in C#)  (make sure `input_pickable` is set to `true`).

---

We can go a different way with `AnimatedSprite2D` since it is a `Node2D` that has a `Texture`, but first we need to figure out which is its current `Texture`. I believe this would suffice:

```
var texture = SpriteFrames.GetFrameTexture(Frame);
```

Having the texture, the next step is to figure out its size and position.

We can get the size of the texture like this:

```
var textureSize = texture.GetSize();
```

Next we need to figure out its position, which also depends on `Centered` and `Offset`:

```
var texturePosition = (Centered ? (-textureSize * 0.5) : Vector2.ZERO) + Offset;
```

With both size and position, we can make a rect:

```
var textureRect = Rect2.new(texturePosition, textureSize);
```

Except rect is in local coordinates, and we get the input position in viewport coordinates, so we need to convert it... If I'm not mistaken, this is how you do it:

```
var clickPosition = GetViewport().CanvasTransform.AffineInverse() * e.Position;
```

Although, it would be easier to use (exept this won't work for touch):

```
var clickPosition = GetLocalMousePosition():
```

And finally check if that position is inside the rect:

```
if (textureRect.HasPoint(clickPosition)
{
    Stop();
}
```