# How do I create a click and drag system for a sprite in Godot?

Tags: 2d, mouse, godot

I'm working on a game in Godot and I'm trying to create a system where I can click and hold onto a sprite and drag to move that same sprite but I'm having a bit of trouble figuring it out.

I've tried solutions such as looking for a mouse node, looking for mouse signals etc but couldn't find anything for either of them. I've also tried checking for coordinates of the mouse and moving it there but couldn't find a way to do this either. I've been trying to figure this out for a while so I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Godot built-in drag and drop support only exist for `Control`s not for `Node2D` (such as `Sprite2D`). So, first consider if you actually need a `Sprite2D` or would `TextureRect` be better. The `Sprite2D` is a graphic object in the 2D game world, and the `TextureRect` is a graphic object in the UI.

---

Now, if you really want to drag an `Sprite2D`... We can break the problem twofold:

- Detect if the user clicked the `Sprite2D` (for which I recommend using an `Area2D`). See also [How can I detect clicks on an AnimatedSprite2D in Godot with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78183611/402022)
- Have the `Sprite2D` follow the pointer... The simplest implementation would be changing the `global_position` of `Sprite2D` to `get_global_mouse_position` in `_process`.